# paginate_links() on custom loop outputs extra empty pages

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a custom loop:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$works = new WP_Query('category_name=work&posts_per_page=9&paged=' . $paged);
```

Pagination outputs 3 pages, on first there are 9 posts, which is also total number of posts, and on pages 2 and 3 there are no posts (there should be no pages if there are no posts on them, right?)

Here is my paginate_links():

```
<?php elseif ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() || is_category() ) ) : // navigation links for home, archive, and search pages ?>

    <?php 
        global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999;

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'prev_text' => '',
        'next_text' => '',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );

    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

On default loop everything is fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using $wp_query to get the total number of pages. Use your custom query ($works) instead of globalising $wp_query.

Comment: but would this mean that I need separate pagination function for each loop? I have few custom loops and default one...

Comment: Each custom loop will have a (potentially) different number of results, so (potentially) a different number of pages to produce, so yes, pagination should be attached to each query - I don't know how it could work any other way(?)